# How do you move a button up or down, left or right and enlarge or shrink it in html

Tags: html, css

I have looked all across the internet and all I have found is that you have to use CSS to do this. However, I don't know what CSS would move it left or right, down or up and enlarge or shrink it. Hopefully, someone knows how to do it. thanks.

Comment: yes, it is true. you need some css for your styling (move a button up or down, left or right, enlarge and shrink), and yes, someone knows how to do it. is that the question?

Comment: @Kevin Yes Kevin that is exactly the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving the button let's imagine that the Button's class is btn

```
<button class='btn'>Click Me!</button>
```

To move the button 5 to right 4 to left 2 to up and 4 to down the css would be

```
.btn {
  position:relative;
  right:5;
  left:4;
  top:2;
  bottom:4;
}
```

And for shrinking the button you can set the padding accordingly

```
.btn{
  padding:5;
}
```